# R.E or non R.E?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

$L_1= \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \text{ is strings of length between } 1 \text{ and } 5 \}$.

$L_2 = \{  \langle M \rangle \mid  L(M) \text{ is strings of length at most } 5\}$.

I am able to figure out that both languages are undecidable as we can have $TM_{yes}$ and $TM_{no}$ and as per Rice's theorem it's undecidable . But I am having difficulty in proving whether the language is R.E or non R.E .

Can someone please help me?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: both $\overline{L}_1$ and $\overline{L}_2$ are recursively enumerable. For example, to show that $\overline{L}_1$ is r.e., given $\langle M \rangle$ use [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)) until you find a string $w$ accepted by $M$ and having length $0$ or greater than $5$. If such string is found, then accept $\langle M \rangle$. This means that if both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not recursive (as you claim) then $L_1$ and $L_2$ cannot be r.e., since this would imply that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are recursive.

Comment: For L1, we have finite number of strings of length between 1 and 5 so we can simulate all these strings on each TM in an interleaved manner (dovetailing) and hence it's R.E right ? For L2, $TM_{yes} = \phi$ and $TM_{no}$ = any string of length greater than 5. As $TM_{yes}$ is subset of $TM_{no}$ , it should be non r.e right ?

Comment: My main doubt is why can't we apply the same logic to L2 ? We have finite amount of strings of length atmost 5 right ? It should also be R.E by dovetailing. But by Rice's theorem it's non r.e as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: If we apply the same logic to L2 then it should be **R.E** but it's **non R.E** by rice theorem .

Comment: @RajeshR Even if you feed all strings of length between $1$ and $5$ to $M$ and observe that $M$ halts on all of them, that does not guarantee that $M$ does not accept another string $w$ of length greater than $5$.  The number of strings is infinite. You cannot check all of them in a finite number of steps. So, dovetailing does not guarantee that $L_1$ is r.e. Similarly for $L_2$.

Comment: Ok. Got it now.